# What's wrong with difference equations (disease modelling)?

Tags: inference, modeling, differential-equations

I'm developing a mathematical (SIR-style) model for cholera transmission which I am fitting to data using MCMC. The model is reasonably complex (4 compartments, 6 parameters, simulation over 11200 days, fit to 270 data points) and is externally forced by time-varying temperature and precipitation time-series. When I run the MCMC model (I'm using NIMBLE) using differential equations, the MCMC solver takes over a day to run 10,000 iterations. However, when I use difference equations (with a one-day time step) I can run 1,000,000 iterations in about half that time.

I showed my model to a senior colleague who was very critical about use of difference equations, and was convinced that differential equations were more appropriate. I also note that the use of differential equations over difference equations is the norm in the literature. My question is, why? My assumption was that there must be a significant difference in the model output between the two approaches. But for my model they almost identical (and well within the bounds of data uncertainty). In the below image, the black line is from the difference equation, and the red from the differential equation (using deSolve).

[image]

So, in my case, am I able to get away with difference equations? Or is there some other reason why the use of difference equations is inappropriate when doing disease modelling inference.